# TypeORM - how to reuse entities across many projects?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I've had a few project which is using this same database and entities. How to reuse entities across all of this projects? I don't want to copy all `*.entity.ts` files and then paste to all projects, I want to reuse in some way only one copy of this entities.

here is my typeormConfig:

```
    async createTypeOrmOptions(): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
        return {
            type: 'postgres',
            url: this.dbURL(),
            entities: [join(__dirname, 'entities/*.entity.{js,ts}')],
            migrations: [join(__dirname, 'migrations/*.{js,ts}')],
            subscribers: [],
            migrationsTransactionMode: 'each',
            migrationsRun: true,
            synchronize: true,
            keepConnectionAlive: true
        };
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just have them use the same files?

Comment: No, not copy and paste the files. Literally use the same files. Make the projects use the same files... Make the paths in your config point to the same files...